# Trigger onChange Event from a sibling component in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a custom menu using MUI, which consists of checkboxes, and text.  The onChange event works fine when selecting the checkboxes, but when clicking on the text, nothing is happening.  I've been trying to trigger then onChange event from the text component, but I need to be able to pass the event to the onChange handler, which the text doesn't have.

This is what I have so far:

```
<Menu
    open={showQuickFIlter}
    onClose={() => setShowQuickFilter(false)}
    anchorEl={anchorRef.current}
    anchorOrigin={{vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'right'}}
    transformOrigin={{vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right'}}
>
    {quickfilters.map((filter) => (
        <MenuItem key={filter.quickFilterTitle} value={filter.quickFilterTitle}>
            <Checkbox checked={filter.active} onChange{handleQuickFilterChange} value={filter.quickFilterTitle}/>
            <ListItemText primary={filter.quickFilterTitle} onClick={}/>
        </MenuItem>
    ))}
</Menu>
```

The `handleQuickFilterChange` is expecting a `React.ChangeEvent<HtmlInputElement>`, and I can't seem to get that into the method from the `ListItemText` component.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I was overcomplicating things.

This is what I did. I created a new function:

`const quickFilterChange = (value: string) => {...};`

The `ListItemText` was updated to having the onClick callback as follows:

`<ListItemText ... onClick{() => handleListClick(filter.quickFilterTitle)} />`

and the `Checkbox` stayed the same.

In the `handleQuickFilterChange` function, which I didn't initially include, was updated to the following:

```
const handleQuickFilterChange = (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => { 
    const { 
        target: { value }, 
    } = event;

    //everything below here was moved to quickFilterChange and replaced with the following

    quickFilterChange(value)
};
```

and

```
const handleListClick = (value: string) => {
    quickFilterChange(value);
}
```

was created to send `quickFilterChange` the value it needs to do the work that was removed from the other function.